# Case insensitive routing in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Say I have people accessing routes, like:

```
helloworld.com/APP
HELLOWORLD.COM/APP
helloworld.com/app
```

Only the 3rd link works. The first and second one give me a 404.

How do I configure Flask to have case-insensitive routing, so that people can access my routes even if they type `HeLloWoRLd.com/aPp`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20191002141712if_/http://librelist.com/browser/flask/2011/6/24/case-insensitive-routing/) for a hackish way to do it, and also why it's probably **not a good idea.**

In short: URLs are case-sensitive by [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html), and making them case-insensitive will likely mess with search engine indexing of your site among other potential problems.

The recommended alternative approach is to code a [custom 404 error handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers) which looks for the lower-case version of a mistyped URL and then redirects as appropriate.

Also note that the domain name itself isn't under flask's routing control anyway (and *is* actually case-insensitive already) -- so only the `/app` part matters.